# How to Exclude Files/Folders for SwiftLint Using CocoaPods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swiftlint

## The Problem

When building my xcode Swift project, I am getting violations from SwiftLint (i.e. Empty Count Violations) of files/folders that I exclude in my .swiftlint.yml file, but when specifying those files/folders in the `excluded` section, the violations still occur.

### Code

**.swiftlint.yml**

```
included:

excluded:
  - Pods
  - myproject/API/api_implementation.swift
  - myproject/API
```

**Build Phases Run Script**

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"
```

**Project Structure**

```
/projectroot
    .swiftlint.yml
    Pods/
    myproject/
        API/
            api_implementation.swift
```

Neither `myproject/API/api_implementation.swift` nor the entire directory `myproject/API/` are excluded from the lint!

## The Question

What is incorrect in terms of making this file and folder excluded from the lint? If my syntax is incorrect, what is the correct syntax? If my path is incorrect, where is the SwiftLint file run from? Interestingly, even though the .swiftlint.yml file is in the root of my project, the swiftlint file that is run is in Pods/SwiftLint/

Perhaps the way that Cocoapods requires additional integration for SwiftLint to work would cause this problem. I have tried, however, to empty the Build Phases Run Script, and have confirmed that the .swiftlint.yml file is indeed running on build.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax and content of your `.swiftlint.yml` looks correct to me, but I wonder if the problem comes down to Groups vs Folders in Xcode?

SwiftLint only looks at the location of the source files on disk rather than using the hierarchy shown in the Project Navigator in Xcode.  You need to make sure that the files you expect to be excluded are definitely in the `API` *directory* when you look in Finder, and not just the `API` *group* in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Somehow I ended up with additional symbols such as `U+2067` which aren't seen in a text editor. I managed to remove them in `vim`. Here's a screenshot of `git diff` command after removing unnecessary symbols:
[image]

Maybe it will help